# In an AWS Lambda triggered by Kinesis, is there a reason to use the callback success message?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm new to AWS, and Lambda intricacies in particular.  My current goal is to get a Lambda function listening to a Kinesis stream.  What I'm curious about is, in the case of a Kinesis stream triggering a Lambda function, who is the caller (for purposes of the Lambda's export.handler callback)?  In other words, when the callback is executed on success in the Lambda, who is the caller that receives the success message?  And would this ever be used?

e.g., the starting template for a blank Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
    //  the second arg of this callback is the success message;
    //    in the case of a Kinesis trigger, who receives it?
};
```

Comment: Also useful to know what forces the read pointer for the kinesis shard to update.  an exception does not update the reader pointer... what else does not update a read pointer?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is if the record was successfully processed, you should callback with statusCode 202 to let kinesis know it was a success so that the record is removed from the stream.  However, if it failed to process the record, callback with a different statusCode, in which case the record will be re-tried at a later time.  After 24 hours, and if it's still unsuccessfully processed the record will be removed.

For example:

```
if (success) {
   callback(null, {
        statusCode:200,
        body: "Record was successfully processed"
    })
} else {
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 404,
        body: "Record was not successfully processed"
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The caller of Lambda would be Kinesis and if you don't use the callback, the function will execute till its timeout, costing you more on Lambda running time. Therefore exit routine is needed, when your execution is complete.

Comment: That is good to know. Do you know about the other part of the question? Is the success message used for anything in this scenario?

Comment: On further investigation, the execution of `callback` does not terminate Lambda execution; a Lambda will continue to run past execution of the callback.  So I'm actually quite confused by this answer.  The callback is not an exit routine.

Comment: The Lambda function will be kept HOT, but you won't be charged after exist routine happens. If not it will charge you upto the timeout for each request.

Comment: So it is feasible to issue the callback immediately and then continue using a Lambda for free until the max timeout limit? That doesn't seem like a wise policy for AWS.

Comment: You can't use Lambda for free after callback, since the code will exit, but the lambda will be running(Without cold start for next 5mins) which can immediately handle next request.